# Object returns twice on panel.port.on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I've faced with the issue that data from contentScriptFile returns on each call function in progressive, e.g. for first call it returns  only 1 instance, for second call it returns 2 instances, for third call it returns 3 instances.

main.js:

```
var panel = panels.Panel({
    width: 270,
    height: 255,
    contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("panelScript.js"),
});

function handleClick(state) {
    panel.show({
        position: button
    });
}

panel.on("show", function() {
    panel.port.emit("pane");
});

panel.port.on("check", function(options) {
    panel.hide();
    console.log(options);
});
```

panelScript.js:

```
self.port.on("pane", function onShow() {
    selectChoosen.addEventListener("click", function onClick(event) {
        self.port.emit("check", options());
    }, false);

});

function options() {
    return selectedOptions;
};
```

Could you please help me to figure out how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are adding the click handler every time the onShow handler is called. I think what you want to do instead is:

```
selectChoosen.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);

function onClick(event) {
  self.port.emit("check", options());
}

function options() {
    return selectedOptions;
};
```

...this way you only add the click event listener once.